# How to localize perl package (tar.gz)

Tags: perl, localization, package, gettext

Let's say I have `myscript.tar.gz` package generated by `h2xs -AX myscript` containing `bin/myScript.pl` and `lib/MyPackage/MyModule.pm`. `Makefile.PL` and `MANIFEST` manualy edited so I'm able to install the package and run `myScript.pl`.

myscript.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use MyPackage::MyModule;

my $generator = MyPackage::MyModule->new();
my $value = $generator->getValue();

#And the message to be translated/localized
print "Obtained value was $value";
```

How do I localize my package?

I read this: [How can I add internationalization to my Perl script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164931/how-can-i-add-internationalization-to-my-perl-script) and alike, but it's sort of outdated. I also tried example from libintrl-perl, but I'm not wise from it and couldn't make it work.

Comment: I have not used localization, but after a google search I found [`Dist::Zilla::LocaleTextDomain`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla::LocaleTextDomain). Is this something that you could use?

Comment: I had no experience with Dist::Zilla so when I tried it the first time before posting the question I failed. But it seems it work thanks.

Comment: Great to hear! Please consider [answering your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). (Click the blue button `"Answer your question"` below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Håkon:

### **Solution: Dist:Zilla - instead of h2xs approach.**

In case of using Debian these packages are neccessary: `libdist-zilla-perl libdist-zilla-localetextdomain-perl libdist-zilla-plugin-localemsgfmt-perl`

First start with dzil init

```
$ dzil setup
```

Next create a new package:

```
$ dzil new myscript
```

then basically follow [Dist::Zilla::LocaleTextDomain](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla::LocaleTextDomain) and 
use this in a script/module to be translated:

```
use Locale::TextDomain "myscript";
#and format strings like this:
print __ "Obtaining value...";
print __x("Obtained value was {value}", value => $value);
```

add this to `dist.ini`:

```
[LocaleTextDomain]
textdomain = myscript
```

scan for messages/strings to be translated:

```
$ dzil msg-scan
```

initialize language translation files:

```
$ dzil msg-init en us ...
```

translate `*.po` files in `po/` directory

possibly test:

```
$ dzil msg-compile po/en.po
$ LANGUAGE=en perl -Ilib -CAS -I. bin/myScript.pl
```

and remove language test dir after

```
$ rm LocaleData/ -r
```

now just create package:

```
$dzil release
```

and enjoy the beautiful .tar.gz package. 
During the release process Dist::Zilla offers to upload the module to [PAUSE](https://pause.perl.org/pause/query?ACTION=pause_04about), but defaults to not to upload (still figuring out how to prevent the offer).

It's actually more convenient  - no MANIFEST to include files just throw them to `lib/` and `bin/`- It's magic! :)

I hope someone else will find this usefull too.